# What is this convergence theorem?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

Let $w_k$ be a Cauchy sequence of functions continuously differentiable in the closure of $D$. By Schwarz inequality, $$\left[ \int_D (w_k - w) \phi dx\right]^2 \le \int_D (w_k - w)^2 dx \int_D \phi^2 dx.$$
Then we have $$\lim_{k\to \infty} \int_D w_k \phi dx = \int_D w \phi dx,$$ for any trial function $\phi$ with an integrable square.

Comment: This says the following:

Strong convergence in the $L^2-$sense implies weak convergence in the $L^2-$sense.

Comment: I downvoted, because the question is poorly written. You didn't even write the fundamental assumption that $\int_D (w_n-w)^2\,dx\to 0$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Sorry, I added an assumption to it. How do you think of the question now?

Comment: @user546106 Clearly... just read what you wrote and apply linearity of integrals.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Suppose we know that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_D (w_k - w)^2 dx = 0$, do we still need Schwarz inequality to show the weak convergence?

Comment: Yes, we do need the inequality.